# My Media Keys can't be identified

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I tried to identify my media Keys to rebind them. Got [this](http://www.trust.com/en/product/20596-classicline-multimedia-keyboard) cheap keyboard with those 5 multimedia keys. The last one, supposed to open my Music Player, opens instead Windows Media Player and I can't find a way to stop it from doing so. I decided to turn mute and Music player into "Volume Down" and "Volume up" (way more useful). Problem is: I can't get their keycode. I tried with SharpKeys, but all the multimedia keys are 00_100 and when I try to rebind them SharpKeys gives error. Also tried with KeyTweak, and just as with SharpKeys all the Multimedia Keys show the same code and are not rebindable. I decided to try with [Keyboard Code Display](http://www.delphiforfun.org/Programs/Utilities/KeyCodes.htm#Download) and then script them with AHK, but it didn't recognize the keys, just showed "Disabled".

How do I get to rebind those keys?

Also, the Keyboard has, next to the Shutdown and Sleep button, a "Turn On" button (I guess? Trust doesn't exactly explain their keyboard) which does *literally* nothing. When the PC is on nothing happens, when it is off nothing happens, when it is sleeping either every key or no key turns it on. The Keyboard Remap utilities don't even realize its existence (when pressed nothing happens). Any hint about this dude?